# bitcoind deamon create new account for every user

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoind, address, address-generation

I'm new to this bitcoin and seems confused a little.

I need a system where I need to create `new address for every user`(personal account) where they will transfer some bitcoins to it and buy some products from my website.

So, I've started `bitcoind` and through `bitcoin-cli`, I've generated new address(`getnewaddress`) and send some bitcoins to it.

But on the transactions screen, it shows `payment to yourself` and the balance of the account doesn't change.

Can anyone, please help me how to create a `new individual account address` for every user and make the transactions. It should have a `password or a private key` also for security.

NPM Package I used : https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcoin-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin-Core can manage different 'accounts'.
You can can create a new account by using 'getnewaddress':

```
bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "accountname"
```

If the account name exists, the address will be added to that account,
otherwise it will create a new account with that name.
You can see what accounts you have by using 'listaccounts'

For other options see: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Note that these accounts are still considered part of a same "wallet", as it they belong to the same user.

If you want to separate them completely, you can run different instances by using different data folders.
Use the '-datadir=/path/to/data' option when running bitcoin (and again everytime you use 'bitcoin-cli') to tell bitcoin which "account" it has to use.

E.g.:

```
bitcoind -datadir=/home/user/btc1/ -daemon
bitcoind -datadir=/home/user/btc2/ -daemon
bitcoin-cli -datadir=/home/user/btc1/ sendtoaddress <address-of-btc2> <amount>
```

Note that you can also use different configurations by placing different bitcoin.conf files inside each data folder.

Comment: Completely removed from bitcoin now...

Comment: Please be more specific. What has been removed?

Answer (score 2):

Listaccounts is deprecated and will be removed in V0.18. To use this command, start bitcoind with -deprecatedrpc=accounts. (code -32)